# Sublime Text, custom location Data/Packages

Tags: sublimetext

When I'm updating my snippets etc. and switch to my laptop I have to copy and update my snippets twice every time.

I'm using the portable version of ST and it would be nice if I could have a custom location for my Packages folder so I could sync it without syncing the whole sublime folder.

Comment: Have you seen: https://packagecontrol.io/docs/syncing ?

Comment: @OdatNurd thanks, but this doesn't work, I need my snippets synced, and they are not part of the publick packages.

Comment: The instructions there will sync your `User` package, and that will cause all other packages that are installed to sync. If you're making custom snippets, you should be putting them in your `User` package. If for some reason you don't want to, use those instructions but substitute the package name for `User`

Comment: Hmm, it looks promising. I've never heard about 'mklink' before, but I don't like "overwriting" the file table with splits and merges. I just feel I will forget I made the link and mess up something. Folder permissions and moving folders are complicated enough already. I would prefer to change the path inside sublime config, but I guess it's not possible.

Comment: @OdatNurd I thought my JS-snippets had to be in 'Sublime Text 4\Data\Packages\JavaScript' but they are scoped inside each snippet, so I guess sublime just loads every '.sublime-snippet'-file in Data?

Comment: Yes, snippets can exist in any package; it's the content that attaches them to a specific type of file, not the location they're stored in.